# MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice crash

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

My scenekit app got rejected from review, because of a crash. In the symbolicated crash logfile, I can see that it happens at MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice. The same version works in testflight on my devices.

Most of the SCNNodes just contain colors or images. I don't use shaders. There is one SKVideoNode with a mp4 file and one 3D-Object (SCNNode(MDLObject:obj) with .obj).

How can I fix this?

Or can it have something to do with the app size or IPV6, because the app is larger than 100MB and I only tested on WLAN?

Thanks!

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

...


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.superoom.SuperoomV0x12736dda0
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018173411c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181800ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001816a5dac abort + 140
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018167ae54 __assert_rtn + 284
4   Metal                           0x0000000183cd133c MTLReportFailure + 480
5   Metal                           0x0000000183cb6350 -[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:] + 584
6   AGXMetalG4G                     0x0000000105167060 0x105148000 + 127072
7   SceneKit                        0x00000001905c35f0 -[SCNMetalResourceManager _newTextureWithDescriptor:] + 52
8   SceneKit                        0x00000001905c39f4 -[SCNMetalResourceManager _fillTexture:slice:image:textureImageType:needsMipMap:] + 668
9   SceneKit                        0x00000001905c4120 -[SCNMetalResourceManager renderResourceForImage:sampler:] + 340
10  SceneKit                        0x0000000190601d70 __41+[SCNRenderContextMetal registerBindings]_block_invoke_17 + 172
11  SceneKit                        0x000000019060065c -[SCNRenderContextMetal _execute:] + 2928
12  SceneKit                        0x0000000190600dc0 -[SCNRenderContextMetal drawRenderElement:withPass:] + 416
13  SceneKit                        0x0000000190608658 C3DEnginePipelineRenderSubTree + 1140
14  SceneKit                        0x00000001905d719c C3DEngineContextRenderNodeTree + 440
15  SceneKit                        0x00000001906d7d88 _drawScene + 184
16  SceneKit                        0x00000001906d5f5c __C3DEngineContextRenderPassInstance + 372
17  SceneKit                        0x00000001906d7040 C3DEngineContextRenderMainTechnique + 1352
18  SceneKit                        0x0000000190676d48 -[SCNRenderer _renderScene:sceneTime:] + 364
19  SceneKit                        0x0000000190676e98 -[SCNRenderer _drawSceneWithNewRenderer:] + 264
20  SceneKit                        0x0000000190677398 -[SCNRenderer _drawScene:] + 84
21  SceneKit                        0x000000019067769c -[SCNRenderer _draw] + 636
22  SceneKit                        0x00000001906d0a8c -[SCNView _drawAtTime:] + 464
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001815e547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001815f0728 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 100
25  SceneKit                        0x00000001906d2508 -[SCNView displayLayer:] + 96
26  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184697508 CA::Layer::display() + 140
27  QuartzCore                      0x00000001846797b0 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 228
28  QuartzCore                      0x000000018467949c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 44
29  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184678ac0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
30  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184678820 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
31  UIKit                           0x0000000186ce25f8 _afterCACommitHandler + 180
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181b50728 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181b4e4cc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181b4e8fc __CFRunLoopRun + 928
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a78c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
36  GraphicsServices                0x0000000183360088 GSEventRunModal + 180
37  UIKit                           0x0000000186d5a088 UIApplicationMain + 204
38  superoom                        0x0000000100013674 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001816168b8 start + 4
```

Comment: There are many conditions that can cause a validation error of this type. Can you describe a little more about how you're using SceneKit (in particular, whether you're doing anything with program objects and/or shader modifiers, and if any of your material properties use textures that are anything other than 2D (3D, cube, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added something to the post.

Comment: @JanF.  I am facing the same crash. got any clue?

Comment: sorry, no, didn't follow this anymore.